# Is spring-cloud-stream-binder already supports using Kinesis enhanced fan-out?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, kinesis-stream

I can't find any documentation that explains how to integrate with Kinesis enhanced fan-out.
Still, is there such a possibility?

example of my configuration:

```
spring:
   clouds:
     streams:
       bindings:
         consumeRequest-in-0:
           destination: dev-kinesis
           content-type: application/json
           group: dev-kinesis-grm
       functions:
         definition: consumeRequest
       kinesis:
         bindings:
           consumeRequest-in-0:
             consumer:
               listener-mode: batch
               records-limit: 100
               shard-iterator-type: LATEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do support it since version `4.0.0` of this Kinesis Binder: https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/27/spring-integration-for-aws-3-0-0-m2-and-spring-cloud-stream-kinesis-binder-4.

It is only a part of KCL configuration though.
We couldn't do anything until we have updated to the latest AWS Java SDK v2.

We are going to release GA somewhere in May.

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful.
Does it need special settings to register for Kinesis as a fan-out?

Comment: Just only this one: `kplKclEnabled=true`